# Link jquery.cookie.js from google code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-code, jquery-cookie

Could one link the latest `jquery.cookie.js` from google code instead of having a local copy?

if yes, could someone provide me the link for it so I can link it in my page.

thanks!

Comment: Google CDN doesn't host it try jsdeliver instead http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!jquery.cookie or cdnjs http://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-cookie/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cdnjs and jsdelivr link is here

```
http://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-cookie/
http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!jquery.cookie
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, it's not on the Google CDN. All the libraries on the CDN are listed here - http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/